# Is using MapServer to merge several MapLayers on runtime to use with Leaflet a good idea?

Tags: leaflet, mapserver

**MY PROBLEM**

We´re doing a Project right now where we have to display a huge image (containing chemical compounds and elements, so not geo referenced) as a map within a Web-Application (with `Leaflet`). The image itself is an Adobe Illustrator-File, so its actually a bunch of vector graphics. To makes things easy, we just converted it into a large .png (27.000x19.000 px) and then used `MapTiler` to create the needed MapRessources for Leaflet, easily included within a `TileLayer`.

The **Problem** is:
The user needs to be able to dynamically add and remove different Layers (== Filter) of the map to show more or less informationes from the picture. So we first created those layers within the Illustrator-File, then exported every layer as its own transparent .png-File, mapTiled it and included it as an own Leaflet-Layer.

Right now, we have 6 Filter-Layers and two more base Layers for the background and an overlay. This means that when all Filters are activated (which is the default), we have 8 Leaflet-Layers stacked on top of each other at once. As you can imagine, this causes some performance issues in the Browser, since Leaflet has to load and render 8 Layers with all its Tiles (depending on Screen size up to 25 at once) for every zoom or drag-action. Its still in a point that is not impossible to bear, but we are expecting several more filters to come and therefore wanna stay scalable in the future.

This means we will somehow have to change our approach of generating the Layers.

**MY APPROACH SO FAR**

Since we actually have a vector-graphics based map, i thought there have to be better alternatives. But it seems that we have a rare case of requirements, since my researches mostly ended in dead ends, especially since most of the cases only cover REAL geographical maps, but what we have is a raster map. I also thought about somehow putting the map into a GeoJSON or redraw it somehow directly with SVG, but since we have LOTS of single elements on the map (> 20k), I dont think this would perform much better.

So I kind of need to stay with the Bitmaps, and therfore my main goal is simple: I wanna reduce the number of layers by merging the tiles of the currently activated Filter into one single .png which then gets delivered to leaflet within ONE Layer. I spent some hours now researching, but I always run into dead ends since it seems we have a rare case of requirements here (especially since most people deal with georeferenced data, not with custom raster maps).

So right now, I can think of 2 different options:

1. Create ONE Layer for every Filter-Combination. This means we would have to create 2^n layers, so this would only work up to a certain number of filters (which probably will increase) - therefore, i would prefer another solution (this is only last case)
2. Use `MapServer` and somehow import my Layers. Then we could merge the Layers on runtime with a query (I read about `Union Layer` [here](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/union.html)) and therefore only deliver ONE Layer to leaflet.

**MY QUESTION**

I have absolutely no experience with `MapServer` and im therefore not even sure if that is a use-case or if its capabale of doing this, and more important: If it would really give us a performacne boost, since it probably requires a lot of logic ServerSide.

Before i start spending another hours to try this out:
Can someone who already worked with `MapServer` give me some feedback if that is even a good idea or if I am misunderstanding something with `MapServer` completely?

Also, if someone has another alternative or idea for me, you´re more than welcome to share it, im grateful for every input. :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at OpenLayers where you can display a mix of raster and vector layers. another option might be mapcache a tile caching engine part of the mapserver project. This has the ability to do vertical assembly of tiles. So if you case where you have 8 layers you can ask mapcache to stack all the  eight tiles into a single tile. You can give it a list of layers to stack and it takes care of it for you. You can also do this with mapserver. The difference being that mapcache is a lightweight apache module that just works with tiles and is probably a little faster. Mapserver is a cgi-bin process and work efficiently at rendering and combining raster layers but is probably not as fast as mapcache for simple assembly of tiles.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I also thought about OpenLayers, but this would mean we would have to change the whole Frontend, what would be a more "future task". But im definitly gonna have a look into `MapCache`, sounds super promising. Im gonna let you know how it went and mark as an answer if its my solution.

Comment: You can display vectors in mapserver and mix them with rasters. My reference to OpenLayers and vectors is that you can have a vector feature layer where the vectors are rendered and managed by OpenLayers, but this has a limit on the number of vectors before performance kills you. OpenLayers has some nice simple demo examples where you can get an idea how features work in the browser. Otherwise Leaflet is great and I have been using that for some simple apps. You can build some very nice UI with it.

Comment: I didnt have time yet to evaluate your suggestions, since other Projects got in the way. So sorry for the late "answer"-marking. Thanks a lot again, you put me on a hot trail.